Browse a file using robotframework
I have below .robot file
*** Settings ***
Documentation       Create a travel plan

Library             RPA.Windows
Library             RPA.Desktop
Library             Dialogs
Library             OperatingSystem
Library             TravelApplication.py


*** Test Cases ***
Create travel plan
    Given I launch the build exe file
    And I browse travel excel file


*** Keywords ***
I launch the build exe file
    Windows Run    build_10.exe

I browse travel excel file
    enter travel file path

For the keyword `enter travel file path`

and I have a Class TravelApplication.py
from time import time, sleep
from RPA.Desktop.Windows import Windows

win = Windows()

class TravelApplication():

def enter_travel_file_path(self):
    

I have tried win.get_Window_elements and win.get_window_list but failing to figure how out to enter file path here
Expectation is to first verify that File browse dialog is open, if open enter file path and hit enter


I am trying these libraries
Library             RPA.Windows
Library             RPA.Desktop
Library             Dialogs
Library             OperatingSystem
and package is robotframework installed by pip install  "git+https://github.com/rasjani/rpaframework.git#egg=rpaframework&subdirectory=packages/main"
Edit:
I browse travel excel file
  Control Window    Open
    # RPA.Windows.Click    name:Cancel
    RPA.Windows.Set Focus    name:"File name:"
    RPA.Windows.Send Keys
    ...    name:"File name:"
    ...    "C:\Users\travel.xlsx"

This doesn't give any error but also doesn't paste any thing in file path area.
